# Spring: two configs of ObjectMapper

Tags: spring, jackson, objectmapper

I use both Kafka and @RestController in my Spring Boot project.
And I need to declare two different configs of ObjectMapper (Jackson) for @RestController and my Kafka classes.
One of them which is for Kafka looks like this:

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public ObjectMapper newJacksonJsonProvider() {
        SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule();
        module.addDeserializer(ZonedDateTime.class, new ZonedDateTimeCustomDeserializer());
        return new ObjectMapper()
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true)
                .setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE)
                .configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
                .registerModule(new ParameterNamesModule())
                .registerModule(module);
    }
```

for the rest controllers I need a basic one. Or just a one which won't be conflicting with the above one.

Also, I use a multi-module project. So, maybe there is a possibility how to separate it, so there will be no collision.

Answer (score 1):

So if you really just need two instances of ObjectMapper, then I would suggest you should actually make the other one @Primary, and inject the custom one wherever you specifically need it using the @Qualifier annotation like so:

```
@Bean(name = "defaultObjectMapper")
@Primary
ObjectMapper defaultObjectMapper() {
    return new ObjectMapper();
}

@Bean(name = "customizedObjectMapper")
ObjectMapper customizedObjectMapper() {
    var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    //customization goes here
    return objectMapper;    
}
```

Then you can autowire the customized one where you need it like so:

```
//constructor for a service that requires the custom ObjectMapper
ServiceUsingAutowiredObjectMapper(@Qualifier("customizedObjectMapper") ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
//code goes here
}
```

However, since you specifically mentioned Kafka I feel like you probably could rather configure JsonSerializer/Deserializer for Kafka specifically without exposing that customized ObjectMapper as a bean.
(see [spring kafka docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#tip-json) for details on using custom serializer/deserializer for Kafka)

Comment: Use the Spring provided `JacksonObjectMapperBuilder` to benefit from easier configuration and autodetection of modules on the classpath instead of manually needing to declare those.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the tricky part here is injecting those custom object mappers into spring beans (in my case it is config of @RestController) or other dependencies (in my case it is Kafka).

Comment: to be more precise, I use org.springframework.messaging for Kafka.

Comment: ok, maybe this can be a solution
```
@Configuration
public class WebConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.stream().filter(c -> c instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter).forEach(c -> {
            ((MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) c).setObjectMapper(new ObjectMapper()); //set default mapper
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: You really shouldn’t instantiate a new ObjectMapper() in a loop here, and your HttpMessageControllers actually would have the basic ObjectMapper injected anyway if you use the @Primary annotation on it.